# canonical meaning of tbl_lazy and related classes

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, dbplyr, method-dispatch

I have an internal package that uses S3 method dispatch to enable *lazy* operations on what are likely large tables. Currently, I support:

- `"data.frame"`, in the case where I already downloaded a satisfying subset;
- `"Dataset"`, derived from `arrow::open_dataset`; I chose this (out of several, see below) because it seemed the most agnostic to whatever arrow could throw my way (e.g., local parquet file or Arrow Flight);
- `"arrow_dplyr_query"`, where the arrow connection has been "touched" by a dplyr lazy operation;
- for legacy reasons, I also dispatch on database connections (e.g., `"Microsoft SQL Server"`) and deal with the SQL literally.

I'd like to add a dbplyr connection (e.g., `tbl(con, "TableName")`), and it inherits multiple classes:

```r
class(tb)
# [1] "tbl_Microsoft SQL Server" "tbl_dbi"                  "tbl_sql"                  "tbl_lazy"                
# [5] "tbl"
```

I'm having a difficult time determining which is best (by definition or intent) for this purpose. `tbl` might be okay, but is fairly close to `data.frame`, will it fail me? Since there are actually multiple DBMS types in use (beyond mssql), I don't want to choose the first. I believe `tbl_dbi`, `tbl_sql`, and `tbl_lazy` will likely all satisfy the intent.

I believe that often classes have formality merely in the functions written to dispatch on them. Since I don't know how the authors intend these to be used (other than inferring from the functions that dispatch), are there risks with using the (seemingly) top level `"tbl"` for dispatch?

Some example classes:

```r
library(dplyr)
# con <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
tb <- tbl(con, "TableName")
pq <- arrow::open_dataset("myfile.pq")

class(pq)
# [1] "FileSystemDataset" "Dataset"           "ArrowObject"       "R6"               
pq %>%
  filter(Name == "ABC") %>%
  class()
# [1] "arrow_dplyr_query"

class(tb)
# [1] "tbl_Microsoft SQL Server" "tbl_dbi"                  "tbl_sql"                  "tbl_lazy"                
# [5] "tbl"                     
tb %>%
  filter(Name == "ABC") %>%
  class()
# [1] "tbl_Microsoft SQL Server" "tbl_dbi"                  "tbl_sql"                  "tbl_lazy"                
# [5] "tbl"
```

Comment: Based on [this tibble vignette](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/extending.html#data-frame-subclasses), the `tbl` class is responsible for print behavior. I think in this case, dispatching on `tbl_sql` would be closer to your intent; however, dispatching on `tbl` probably wouldn't be an issue though, since further S3 method calls on the object *should* dispatch on the remaining classes (i.e. `tbl_Microsoft SQL Server`).